# Подключение к PDO с использованием namespace

Tags: pdo, php, namespace

Привет.

Не могу подключиться к PDO (переделываю проект с использованием неймспесов)

Есть класс подключения к БД:

```
namespace Application\Models;

use \PDO;
use \PDOException;

class DBConnect 
{
    public function openConnection()
    {
        // set the options of the PDO connection:
        $options = array(PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_OBJ, PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION, PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => 'SET NAMES utf8');

        // generate connection
        try {
            return new PDO(DB_TYPE . ':host=' . DB_HOST . ';dbname=' . DB_NAME . ';charset=utf8', DB_USER, DB_PASS, $options);
        }
        catch(PDOException $e) {
            die("Failed to connect to the database: " . $e->getMessage()); 
        }
    }
}
```

Я пробовал и **use PDO**, и **use \PDO**, и **return new \PDO** (это все возможные советы на stackoverflow)

Ошибка похоже не связана с PDO, а связана с неймспейсами:

> Warning: require(Application/Models/PDO.php): failed to open stream

Если я пишу  **use \Application\PDO**, то ошибка другая:

> Warning: require(Application/PDO.php): failed to open stream

То есть оно как бы не воспринимает обратный слэш как выход в глобальную область видимости. Подскажите, пожалуйста.

p.s Прикладываю код автолодера:

```
    function autoload($className)
{
    $className = ltrim($className, '\\');
    $fileName  = '';
    $namespace = '';
    if ($lastNsPos = strrpos($className, '\\')) {
        $namespace = substr($className, 0, $lastNsPos);
        $className = substr($className, $lastNsPos + 1);
        $fileName  = str_replace('\\', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, $namespace) . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;
    }
    $fileName .= str_replace('_', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, $className) . '.php';

    require $fileName;
}

spl_autoload_register('autoload');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Потому что, видимо, класс сначала ищется в текущем неймспейсе, и реквайрится файл, потому что вы в своем автолоадере не проверяете вообще наличие этого файла; как минимум, можно было бы прочитать в тексте ошибке то, что проблемы с файлом, а не с тем, что класс так и не найден. `return new \PDO`, впрочем, должен был бы отработать нормально.

Нет ничего плохого в том, чтобы не писать автолоад самому, а взять [уже готовый пример из PSR](https://github.com/php-fig/fig-standards/blob/master/accepted/PSR-4-autoloader-examples.md) и чуть-чуть поправить. Я уж молчу про использование [composer](https://getcomposer.org), который после небольшого [тюнинга конфига](https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#psr-4) сам сгенерирует загрузчик как на ваши классы, так и на ваши зависисмости.

**Обновление**

[[@silent-box](/users/17284/silent-box)](/users/17284/silent-box), ого, странно что у них там нет проверок.

Там не сам $fileName надо проверять, а существование файла:

```
if (file_exists($fileName)) {
    include $fileName;
}
```

В этом случае, если файл не нашелся, управление передастся следующему обработчику, который, возможно, знает больше и найдет-таки файл. А если обработчиков больше нет - то тогда будет ошибка о *ненайденном классе*, какая и должна появиться, если ни один автозагрузчик не смог найти класс.

И да, на фоне общего потока вопросов - за использование стандарта огромный респект.

Comment: Вы правы, спасибо большое.

Я понимаю что поряком умнее - пользоваться стандартом, чем писать велосипед (в данном случае)

Но я и взял стандарт :) 
https://github.com/php-fig/fig-standards/blob/master/accepted/PSR-0.md

Ссылки именно на короткий вариант в 15 строк (внизу по ссылке) - встречал в нескольких авторитетных местах, до последнего момента не верил что там ошибка

Заменил  require $fileName; на if ($fileName !== false) require $fileName;

вроде работает)

Comment: Обновил ответ

Comment: Спасибо! Сделаю именно так.